# What is the "AP" on the Raspberry Pi, from the FAQ?

Tags: temperature

In the temperature FAQ, it "the LAN9512 is specified by the manufacturers being qualified from 0°C to 70°C, while the **AP** is qualified from -40°C to 85°C."

Does anyone know what the **"AP"** is? Is it the Access Point, in other words the Ethernet connection?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect, Applications Processor.

From http://www.broadcom.com/products/BCM2835

"The BCM2835 is a cost-optimized, full HD, multimedia applications processor for advanced mobile and embedded applications.. "

Answer (score 2):

considering:

1. the FAQ part where this was posted is named "Graphics"
2. two hottest chips on the board are BCM2835 and LAN9512 ([source](http://www.geektopia.es/es/technology/2012/06/22/articulos/se-calienta-el-ordenador-raspberry-pi-estudio-de-sus-temperaturas-en-funcionamiento.html)).
3. there are quite a lot of places on the web, where the BCM2835 is mentioned nearby 85°C.

I think it was a typo, and the author actually meant combined CPU/GPU unit.